# Which packages should be installed on Ubuntu server so it will be able to play video?

Tags: server, video, xvfb

I have a server where Ubuntu Server 12.04 is installed. It's used for running automated browser tests. The tests use Firefox that is run in Xvfb. One of tests clicks button that usually invokes playing HTML5 video. However, video isn't played. I think it's because Ubuntu server lacks packages that are needed for playing video that are present on Ubuntu desktop by default.

Which packages should I install to be able to play video?

The Content-type of the video is `video/mp4`, an extension of the file is `.mp4`

Comment: play video by browser or by video player .

Comment: @nux as I told it's not played by browser

Answer (score 2):

To be able to play most audio and video formats, install Ubuntu Restricted Extras:
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

**Edit**
To find out which codec you need:
`sudo apt-get install libav-tools`
`ffprobe -show_streams "file.mp4"`

It'll probably be AAC for audo and H.264 for video.
Support to decode `MPEG-4 AAC` is provided by [gstreamer1.0-libav](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gstreamer1.0-libav&searchon=names) and to decode `H.264` there is [gstreamr0.10-ffmpeg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg&searchon=names):

`sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`